# Using cif format video to create wmv or mpeg

Tags: matlab, video-processing

As I have understood the very commonly found video 'foreman.cif', the CIF is the raw format of the video which has not undergone any kind of encoding/compression.
Can this 'forman.cif' video be compressed to form a .wmv or .mpeg video.?

Many of the research scholars have used this video 'foreman.cif', but the VideoReader function in matlab says that it doesn't have the required codec to run the file!

Comment: Use a conversion tool - you could try https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: What I meant is .. How can the .CIF format be used in matlab.... my problem is that ..the matlab is not at all recognizing the CIF format..it says..unable to determine the format required...

Comment: You may want to change the title and clarify that point. Your current title very strongly implies that you wish to convert a video between formats.